# I have a problem with the in django search function

Tags: django, search

I have a problem with my search function.
He's tasked to search for movies by name
and I don't know how to write it and it works

My Views:

```
class AllMovies(ListView):
    model = Movie
    template_name = 'All_movies.html'
    cats = Category.objects.all()


    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cat_menu = Category.objects.all()
        search_term = ''
        context = super(AllMovies, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["cat_menu"] = cat_menu
        return context

    def search(request):  # wszytskie filmy (lista)
        movier = Movie.objects.all()

        search_term = ''
        if 'search' in request.GET:
            search_term = request.GET['search']
            movier = Movie.objects.filter(name__icontains=search_term)
        paginator = Paginator(movier, 30)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        movier = paginator.get_page(page)
        get_dict_copy = request.GET.copy()
        params = get_dict_copy.pop('page', True) and get_dict_copy.urlencode()

        return render(request, 'AllMovies.html',
              {'movie': movie, 'params': params, 'search_term': search_term})
```

Here, two functions should be divided and combined, but I don't know how

My urls:

```
   path("AllMovies/", AllMovies.as_view(), name="AllMovies"),
```

My templates:

```
    <form class="form-inline">
             <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 " align="middle" type="search" placeholder="Name Movie"
                     aria-label="Search" name='search' value = "{{ search_term }}">
              <button class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
     </form>
```

The most important thing is for the search engine to work.
Help me!

Comment: I forgot:
return render(request, 'AllMovies.html',
                  {'movier': movier, 'params': params, 'search_term': search_term})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListView` does not look at a method `search`, regardless of what you write, it will not be triggered.

You can filter the list of objects to return by overriding the [**`.get_queryset(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset):

```
class AllMovies(ListView):
    model = Movie
    template_name = 'All_movies.html'
    paginate_by= 30
    context_object_name = 'movie'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        get_dict_copy = request.GET.copy()
        get_dict_copy.pop('page', True)
        return super().get_context_data(
            *args,
            **kwargs,
            cat_menu=Category.objects.all(),
            search_term=self.request.GET.get('search', '')
            params=get_dict_copy.urlencode()
        )

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'search' in self.request.GET:
            search_term = self.request.GET['search']
            return qs.filter(name__icontains=search_term)
        return qs
```

Comment: Error:
..../views.py", line 32, in get_queryset
    if 'search' in request.GET:
NameError: name 'request' is not defined

Comment: @Kuba: in a class-based view, it is indeed an attribute of `self`, so `self.request` :)

Comment: I do not understand, or should I add?
def get_context_data(self.request, *args, **kwargs):

Comment: @kuba: no, instead of using `'search' in request.GET`, it should be `'search' in self.request.GET` and the same for `serach_term = ...`. I think it would however help to first get used to Python's syntax.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you ,Thank you!> It's working nice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to implement the search in your ListView getting your queryset parameter:

```
class AllMovies(ListView):
    model = Movie
    template_name = 'All_movies.html'
    cats = Category.objects.all()

    if 'search' in request.GET and request.GET['search']:
        search_term = request.GET.get('search')
        movier = Movie.objects.filter(name__icontains=search_term)

    #...
```